# Ubuntu sudo su and server su clarification

Tags: sudo, root, su

I have a question about root. when i want to change to root in ubuntu have to type:

```
sudo su -
```

i am not allowed to type:

```
su
```

and

```
su - root
```

Howerver it works the other way around on my server, what difference is there between those 2 commands?

Comment: I think the difference here is that `su` elevates you to root privileges if you provide the *root* password, and `sudo` elevates you to root privileges if you provide the *user* password.  On your box where you have to execute `sudo su -`, have you set a root password?  If not, it might not let you do `su`.  If you want to,  you can set the root password (it's unset by default on new installs) using `sudo passwd` (you'll have to provide your user password first).

Comment: thanks alot!!! yes the password was not created for the root. and its done now! @rocketman10404

Comment: another question, normally when i am root the color of the text is red, however atm it is not. what can i do to change that?

Comment: There are actually quite a few customizations you can do to your bash prompt, and they can be done globally, or for specific users.  These customizations are done by settings the `PS1` environment variable.  Some quick googling on this topic should point you to lots of documentation and guides.

Comment: thanks alot @rocketman10404 you have been a great help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to get to root by typing in the terminal:

```
sudo -i
```

or you can also type.

```
gksudo thunar
```

there you can also change privileged, and su normal can only go to root whit enter in the terminal:

```
 sudo -i | su
```

could might work fine this way.